# Does the derivative of a holomorphic function $f(t)$ always vanish at multiple roots of $f$?

Tags: transcendental-functions

Does the derivative of a holomorphic function $f(t)$ always vanish at multiple roots of $f$?

I know its true for polynomials, but is it a general fact known to hold for all transcendental functions?

Comment: Try expanding the power series around a multiple root.

Comment: $f$ is holomorphic, let $f(z)=(z-z_0)^mg(z)$ with $g(z_0)\neq0$ and $m>1$.

Comment: Ok.. ${\frac {\partial }{\partial t}} \left(  \left( t-{\it t0} \right) ^{m}
g \left( t \right)  \right)={\frac { \left( t-{\it t0} \right) ^{m}mg \left( t \right) }{t-{\it t0}}}+ \left( t-{\it t0} \right) ^{m}{\frac {d}{dt}}g \left( t \right)$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. Suppose $f$ has a multiple root at $z_0$, so that 
$$\lim_{z\to z_0} \frac{f(z)}{(z-z_0)^2}$$
exists. Now let $g(z) = f(z)/(z-z_0)^2$, such that the value of $g(z_0)$ is given by the above limit. Then $g$ is holomorphic, and 
$$f'(z) = g'(z)(z-z_0)^2 + 2g(z)(z-z_0)$$
and so we see that $f'(z_0) = 0$.